# Feed django web server with desktop program data

Tags: python, django, authentication, request

I am trying to send some database info from a desktop ERP to a django web server that acts as a web interface.
The first thing I've tried that works is using the requests module to "fake" a POST with a file attached to it.
However this is a obviously dirty (yet effective) way to do it.
I use authentication through a session.
Is there a clean(er) way to do this?

My code:

```
headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0',
           'Referer': 'https://auth.afip.gov.ar/contribuyente/',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive',
           }


session = requests.Session()

response = session.get('http://192.168.0.101:8000/sincronizacion/', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

csrf_value = soup.find(attrs={'name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken', })['value']

login_info = {'username': 'user', 'password': 'pass', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_value,
              'next': '/sincronizacion/', }

response = session.post('http://192.168.0.101:8000/login/?next=/sincronizacion/', data=login_info, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

csrf_value = soup.find(attrs={'name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken', })['value']

datos_odontologos = {'test': 'test', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_value} # test represents a future csv attachment

response = session.post('http://192.168.0.101:8000/sincronizacion/', data=datos_odontologos)

print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: That's correct. But I think you don't have to deal with cookies by yourself. requests' Session manage its own cookiejar

Comment: @gawel I tried removing the csrfmiddleware from the post data and got a 403 error.. Maybe we need both the post and cookie data?

Comment: Right. Sorry. You can retrieve the token from a cookie but you have at least to provide a http header, not a cookie https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: You could always mark the view as csrf exempt to simplify this part https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt

Comment: You need to add a header. This should work: s.post(url, data=data, headers={"X-CSRFToken": resp.cookies['csrftoken'])

Comment: Thanks @gawel, that took at least a line per request.. You should make an answer out of that :P "This is the way to do it, but use headers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use the csrf cookie sent by django and send it back via a http header when you're posting some data:

```
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> # get the cookie
>>> resp = session.get(url)
>>> # post data with csrf header using the cookie value
>>> resp = session.post(url, data=data, headers={"X-CSRFToken": resp.cookies['csrftoken'])
```

This way you don't have to parse the html result to get the csrf token or to modify the data sent.

Comment: Excellent! I will add it saved me from using bs4 at all