# Does django's CSRF affect iOS program?

Tags: python, ios, django

I have met this problem today when I try to post data to django from iOS program:
I try to post data to django,but only to find that there exists error "csrf cookie not set",I have solved this problem by forbidding the CSRF function (@csrt_exempt)
but I want to know, if that would bring safety problem to my porgram?
if it would, and is there anyone can tell how to solve it ?

PS:post from iOS to django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application will be vulnerable to CSRF https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Have a look at this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052956/feed-django-web-server-with-desktop-program-data/21095734#21095734

The solution use some python code but you should be able to do that with your iOS framework